# What is the largest brand of duffel bag permitted on domestic flights?

Tags: luggage

[This travel tips](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/airline-checkedin-luggage-size-restrictions-109260.html) mentions:

> The maximum number of linear inches on a checked bag for most airlines is 62 inches. This means that when you add up the length, width and height of the luggage you intend to check, it should not be more than 62 inches.

I'm in the market for as large a duffel bag that I can bring on a domestic US flight. Perhaps `32L, 15W, 15H`, or `38L, 12W, or 12H`. It doesn't matter as long as it hits 62 linear inches.

However, a quick search of Amazon reveals no duffel bags that are exactly 62 inches. The closest I found was [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012PVC3S8) at 55", but all of the other "large" duffel bags peaked at about 50".

What brands for duffel bags are exactly or near 62 linear inches?

Is it possible that companies don't make them exactly 62 inches because packing it to capacity could make it bulge greater than 62 inches?

Comment: Some smaller hockey bags would come just within that limit, though most are oversize. For instance, a [60 inch example](http://www.hockeyoverstock.com/ccmstrtrbag30.html).

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks! Would you like to post that as an answer?

Comment: Note that it's unlikley that all US airlines have the same baggage rules. So picking something at the limt for some airlines is likley to push you over for others.

Comment: I checked the stats on my LL Bean extra large rolling duffle that I've used domestically and internationally for several years...it's 66" but was never questioned--I usually didn't have it packed tight, nor overweight. Bean's listing now explicitly says that it's too big for most domestic flights.